# Correlated uncertainties

Tags: error-propagation, around

navigating through the docs. of `Around` one can read in the details that

> When Around is used in computations, uncertainties are by default
> propagated using a first-order series approximation, assuming no
> correlations.

**Question**: is there any implemented way in which we could calculate correlated uncertainties? Could please someone provide any ref. / example of this?

*Aclaration*: By correlated uncertainties I meant to say that the covariance  of two variables can't be neglected assuming its $\sim 0$, if I understood correctly.

> If the uncertainties are [correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) then covariance must be taken into account. Correlation can arise from two different sources. First, the measurement errors may be correlated. Second, when the underlying values are correlated across a population, the uncertainties in the group averages will be correlated.

If the propagation of the errors, following what `Around` indicates, is calculated by a 1st-order series approximation, I assume that

$$\delta f(x_1,..., x_n) \approx \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 \delta x_1 ^2 + ... \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)^2 \delta x_n ^2 } = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \delta x_i \right)^2}$$

and not

$$\delta f \approx \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \delta x_i\right)^2 + 2 \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n \rho_{x_i x_j} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \delta x_i\right)\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \delta x_j\right)}$$
where $\rho_{x_i x_j}$ is the correlation term between variables.

I apologize beforehand if you find this a naive question

Comment: What do you mean by "correlated uncertainties"? The definition and examples and references  are welcome.

Comment: BTW, the documentation to `Around` follows Napoleon's directions "Write shortly and unclearly".

Comment: @user64494 I reformulate the question: what should we do if variables are correlated between each other? Would you use `Around` still or compute each term of the sum manually?

Comment: You need `VectorAround` to deal with correlated quantities.

Comment: I find the documentation to `VectorAround` poor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of how you use `VectorAround` to do error propagation through a function of 3 variables that are correlated:

```
fun[x_, y_, z_] := x + y^2 + Sin[z]
AroundReplace[
 fun[x, y, z], {x, y, z} -> 
  VectorAround[{1, 2, 4}, {{2, -1/4, 1/3}, {-1/4, 2/3, 1/5}, {1/3, 1/5, 1/2}}]
 ]
```

> Around[4.243197504692072, 3.065729839846241]

Note that the answer is different when you throw away the correlations (which you can do by applying `Around` to `VectorAround`):

```
AroundReplace[
 fun[x, y, z], {x, y, z} -> 
  Around@VectorAround[{1, 2, 4}, {{2, -1/4, 1/3}, {-1/4, 2/3, 1/5}, {1/3, 1/5, 1/2}}]
 ]
```

> Around[4.243197504692072, 3.5889123224473614`]

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `VectorAround` is certainly lacking examples as to how one might want to use that function.  Here's my guess as to how it might be used:

```
(* Define a VectorAround object *)
xy = VectorAround[{x, y}, {{varx, covxy}, {covxy, vary}}]

(* Find the approximate uncertainty for the difference in two correlated random variables *)
AroundReplace[x - y, {x, y} -> xy]
```

[image: Uncertainty for difference in two random variables]

```
(* Now for the ratio *)
AroundReplace[x/y, {x, y} -> xy]
```

[image: Uncertainty for the ratio of two random variables]

```
(* Something more complicated *)
AroundReplace[x^2 Sin[y], {x, y} -> xy]
```

[image: Uncertainty for a more complicated function of two correlated random variables]